# How to display ble device "Name" when running hcitool lescan and btmon?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I had it working once, but can't get it working again.  I'm running:

`./btmon &`

`hcitool lescan`

And output is of the form:

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43                   [hci0] 80215.374212
  LE Advertising Report (0x02)
    Num reports: 1
    Event type: Connectable undirected - ADV_IND (0x00)
    Address type: Public (0x00)
    Address: EC:FE:7E:14:B8:2E (BlueRadios, Inc.)
    Data length: 31
    Flags: 0x06
      LE General Discoverable Mode
      BR/EDR Not Supported
    Company: Taobao (424)
      Data: 03204c915b6101243d84bbfe04a405e601908190037809b3
    RSSI: -75 dBm (0xb5)
```

But it used to show the Name of the device as well.  How do I get it to do that again?

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo btmon | egrep 'Name|RSSI'
```